# In R, how do I restrict a list of lists based on another list?

Tags: r, list

I feel like this must be simpler than I'm making it, but for some reason I've having some real difficulties even figuring out how to ask this question-- please feel free to suggest some better terminology here, because I think I'm even confusing myself. I'm very new to R and I think I am getting confused because I keep trying to accomplish this how I would do it with Python.

Here is the issue I'm trying to address: I have a list of vectors (GO_list) and another vector (Targets). I simply want to create a new list of vectors (NewList) that only contains lists from GO_list if they match a term in my other list (targets).

For example:

```
>GO_list[1:5]

$ENSCPOP00000019422
[1] "GO:0006821" "GO:0055085" "GO:0006897"
$ENSRNOP00000017654
[1] "GO:0000165" "GO:0007169" "GO:0007399"
$ENSMUSP00000000365
[1] "GO:0006351" "GO:0006355" "GO:0006974" "GO:0007049" "GO:0008150" "GO:0040008"
 $ENSCPOP00000019426
[1] "GO:0006470" "GO:0016311"
$ENSCPOP00000019424
[1] "GO:0006886"

>Targets[1:5]
[1] "ENSMUSP00000104347" "ENSMUSP00000081003" "ENSMUSP00000134911" 
[3] "ENSMUSP00000081001" "ENSMUSP00000081002"
```

And so I only want to include GO_list[1] in NewList if ENSCPOP00000019422 is in Targets.

Does this question make sense?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
> x <- list(A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4, E=5)
> target<-list("C","D")
> x[names(x)%in%target]
$C
[1] 3

$D
[1] 4
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! This was very helpful. I used what you wrote here to write this, which I think is what I wanted specifically:
     NewList <- GO_list[names(GO_list)%in%Targets]

The problem now is that I realize there are fewer elements in NewList than in Targets, which technically shouldn't be possible.. and I'm wondering if it is possible to figure out which things went missing. So, is there a %notin% function similar to the %in% function? Thanks again!

Comment: You can use `setdiff(names(list1), names(list2))` to find out names of elements in `list1` but not in `list2`. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check icon if this has solved your problem.